# tmux Ctrl+B not working

Tags: linux, tmux

Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> followed by another command key
usually gives me nothing. 
I have no `.conf` file so I'm not overwriting it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is what I use for my configuration
and I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> as prefix key.

```
set -g prefix ^a
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
unbind %
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
bind N break-pane
# Set status bar
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
# Highlight active window
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg blue

# Set window notifications
setw -g monitor-activity on
set -g visual-activity on

# Automatically set window title
setw -g automatic-rename
```

Test it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,
then after that <kbd>?</kbd>.

Comment: nope nothing. maybe tmux is looking for the wrong file. my tmux.conf is in my home directory and is hidden.

Comment: tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf

Comment: May be your terminal or DE also has the same shortcut. However, I hope you are not just pressing Ctrl+A. Basically, you have to press Ctrl+A and then release keys, then press "?" or any command.

Comment: Ah. Well now I feel like an idiot. Yup that was it, I didn't know you had to release keys. Wow, I need sleep :) Thanks for helping!

Comment: This is all about time... first time i also wonder why the hell its not working... you won't believe, i literally type this on terminal `ctrl+b`  kinda funny... but this post clear doubt..  Just hit `ctrl+b` and right after that hit next key, that will be your command, `c`, `n`, `p` etc... cool trick

Comment: You can try change `set -g prefix ^a` to `set -g prefix ^y` or use other key and check if it works.

Answer (score 98):

I think this deserves a clear **visible** answer which is hidden in form of a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/266725/tmux-ctrl-b-not-working#comment277752_267317) under the first answer.

Assuming the default tmux configuration is being used, novice tmux users please follow the instructions below to split the pane

**To split the pane horizontally**

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
2. Release pressed keys in Step 1
3. Press <kbd>"</kbd> 
   (on many keyboards, this is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>)

**To split the pane vertically**

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
2. Release pressed keys in Step 1
3. Press <kbd>%</kbd> 
   (on many keyboards, this is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>)

The articles I found and referenced below mention `[CTRL B] + [%]` or `[CTRL B] + ["]` or `Ctrl+b "` which implies that we have to press all the keys together but none mentions the important part of releasing the pressed `Ctrl + whatever key` before pressing the another key in sequence in the command to see the desired action.

- [Tmux support arrives for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/06/08/tmux-support-arrives-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/)
- [tmux Tutorial - Split Terminal Windows Easily](http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/tmux-tutorial-split-terminal-windows-easily)

Comment: `Release pressed keys in Step 1` -> This is what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @byxor this question has precisely to do with splitting panes. The answer is works for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - huge help (tmux noob here)

Answer (score 2):

You can type the command tmux detach to detach from the session.
type tmux list-sessions to get a list of active sessions
`tmux list-sessions
0: 1 windows (created Wed Feb 21 12:53:31 2018) [157x75]
1: 1 windows (created Wed Feb 21 12:55:05 2018) [157x75]`

tmux attach-session -t  will attach you to the session

`Example: tmux attach-session -t 0`

Answer (score 1):

#### Basic tmux commands

```sh
tmux                         # start new
tmux new -s myname           # start new with session name
tmux a                       #  (or at, or attach)
tmux a -t myname             # attach to named
tmux ls                      # list sessions
tmux kill-session -t myname  # kill session
tmux ls | grep : | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print substr($1, 0, length($1)-1)}' | xargs kill # Kill all the tmux sessions:
```

#### Tmux config file to make settings

```
cat << EOT > ~/.tmux.conf
set-option -g prefix C-a
unbind-key C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix
set -g base-index 1
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g set-titles on
set -g status-keys vi
set -g history-limit 10000
setw -g mode-keys vi
setw -g monitor-activity on
bind-key v split-window -h
bind-key s split-window -v
#***synchronize-panes***
bind-key x set-window-option synchronize-panes\; display-message "synchronize-panes is now #{?pane_synchronized,on,off}"
EOT
```

#### Navigate between split panes

- <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>: to toggle synchronization mode.
- <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>: to go to right pane
- <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd>, <kbd><</kbd>: to go to left pane
- <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>: detach tmux and go back to original shell.

**Note**: Press Ctrl+a, hand-off keyboard, then press x or < or < d. No need to long press bind-key which is Ctrl+a.

[Source](https://medium.com/@nsvijaydevops/10-steps-to-score-well-in-cka-c5ea552ea9e3)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get any of the tmux functions to work until I installed emacs

```
sudo apt install emacs
```

By default, in Bash, emacs mode is enabled.  If it is not
enabled you can run this in your shell:

```
set -o emacs
```

This allows you to move the cursor in the shell faster than
using the arrow keys alone.  Specific command key
chords/combinations can be used, like so:

- Ctrl-a:  move cursor to the beginning of the line
- Ctrl-e:  move cursor to the end of the line
- Meta-b:  (or Alt-b), move backward one word
- Meta-f:  (or Alt-f), move forward one word
- Ctrl-u:  Cut from cursor to beginning of line
- Ctrl-k:  Cut from cursor to end of line
- Ctrl-w:  Cut previous word
- Ctrl-y:  Paste what you just cut with Ctrl-u, Ctrl-k, or
  Ctrl-w
- Ctrl-_:  Undo last cut (may not work in all terminals)

Now you can navigate the shell like a pro!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not necessarily the right place, but I had been using https://github.com/rse/stmux thinking it was tmux. It turns out the default activator key on stmux isn't CTRL+B but CTRL+A (and the "A" key turns out to be quite far away from B/C on an AZERTY keyboard ^^")

so CTRL+A, release and then press your keys like K for kill