# Tmux nothing happening

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tmux

I just started learning how to use tmux following [this](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/) tutorial.

The problem is, what ever I type in (Ctrl-b c, or any other shortcut), nothing happens. Just nothing. I open tmux and there is a status bar in the lower part of my terminal that says `[0] 0:bash*`, but nothing I can do after that. I have checked, I don't have any tmux.conf files nor anything else and I thought it should work out of the box. I'm on ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found:

A comment on the only answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/266725/tmux-ctrl-b-not-working):

> Maybe your terminal or DE also has the same shortcut. However, I hope you are not just pressing Ctrl+A. Basically, you have to press Ctrl+A and then release keys, then press "?" or any command.

Why isn't this stuff written in the tutorials? How can I possibly know this is the trick. I'm just a newbie. Anyways, works now!